# Lost my passport with F1 visa before leaving to the USA to begin my masters programme

Tags: visas, passports, f1-visas, lost-documents

I lost my passport with my F-1 visa 3 days before leaving to the United States to begin my masters. Can I get an expedited visa appointment and get a new visa? Or can the already approved visa be replaced?

Comment: Where are you? Have you already replaced your passport? I do not know whether you can get an expedited appointment, but the visa can certainly be replaced -- by submitting a fresh visa application and paying the fee again, I suppose.  You'll need the same materials as your previous application plus a new passport and probably some sort of loss report for your previous passport and visa.  You will probably have to delay your departure, I'm afraid. At least the new visa should be granted relatively quickly since you've already been evaluated.

Comment: I am in India. I haven't left the country. I lost it before leaving India. Will I have to take the interview again? Or is there like a different process for this?

Comment: I suspect that you will have to have another interview. The regulations are such that waivers of the interview requirement are very rare as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the State Department, interview wait times are currently [42 days in Mumbai and 18 days in New Delhi](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html).  You may be able to get an expedited appointment:

> Qualifications for an Expedited Interview Appointment
>
> Consular sections overseas may be able to expedite your interview date if there is an urgent, unforeseen situation such as a funeral, medical emergency, or school start date. The process to request an expedited nonimmigrant visa interview varies by location. You should refer to the instructions on the website of the Embassy or Consulate Visa Section  where you will interview, or on their online appointment scheduling site. You will need to provide proof of the need for an earlier appointment.

The last requirement should be pretty easy to meet in your case.